# How to DROP traffic whose source IP is on a blocklist ipset unless the source is on an allowlist ipset in firewalld?

Tags: firewalld, firewalld-zone

I have 2 ipsets: `friends` (allow-list) and `enemies` (block-list).

My default zone (`public`) DROPs all traffic, except certain services (e.g. `http`).

I have edited the `block` zone that comes shipped with firewalld to add `ipset:enemies` as a source.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-ipset=enemies --type='hash:net'
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=drop --add-source=ipset:enemies
```

Firewalld looks at zones alphabetically, and `block` comes before `public`, so will be considered first.

If the source IP matches, it will be DROP it. Fine.

But I want to also have a `friends` list that includes addresses that should never be blocked. So I was thinking that I need something like:

`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=drop --add-source=NOT ipset:friends`

### Things I've tried.

I thought the answer might be 'Rich rules' since you can specify NOT for source in those. But I could not figure out what 'element' or 'action' should be.

Answers I've read on blogs etc. suggest creating new zone, e.g. `a_zone_before_block` with `--add-source=ipset:friends` and `--set-target=ACCEPT`. However, I don't want to blanket ACCEPT traffic from this allow-list; I still want it to use the rules in my `public` zone.

I could fix this problem by duplicating all the details from `public` into the `a_zone_before_block` but adding `source=ipset:friends`, but this feels messy - with duplication comes the problem that the two are not in sync. So I'm hoping there's a better way.

So what I'm after is either:

- a way to say that traffic should be put in the `block` zone if its source is in ipset:enemies *unless* its source is in ipset:friends.

  *OR*
- a way to say if the traffic is in the `block` zone but its source is in `ipset:friends` then change the zone to `public`

  *OR*
- a way to create a zone `000_first` that matches `ipset:friends` and if it matches, it passes onto `public`, skipping the 2nd zone `block`.

  *OR*
- a way to use inheritance in zone declarations.